# Include and path problem

Tags: php

```
<?php
// This is index.php
ob_start();
include 'tem/u.html';
ob_end_flush();
?>

<html>
<!-- This is u.html -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen" /> 
<body>
<p> abc </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Now my problem is when i run h.html -> Ok with style.
But when i run index.php -> Ok without style (because now the index.php include style.css, not tem/style.css)
Need a fix

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with PHP or `include`. This has to do with your browser, and how URLs are interpreted.

When your browser is pointed at `http://xyz.abc/tem/h.html` and asked to load "style.css", it tries to load `http://xyz.abc/tem/style.css` - this is known as a relative url, relative to the current document location.

When your browser is at `http://xyz.abc/index.php` and is asked to load the stylesheet in the same way, it tries `http://xyz.abc/style.css`. Maybe you see the problem?

As for a solution, you might use a domain-relative path for the stylesheet ("/tem/style.css").

Comment: You mean href="/tem/style.css" right?. I know, but i see in WP template, they still use href="style.css" and everything works.

Comment: @Snoob: If that works in WP, maybe they're using a `<base>` tag. Come to think of it, that's a better idea than the solution I gave in my answer.

Comment: Yes, they use bloginfo('stylesheet_url'). now i know what to do

Answer (score 2):

If possible, refer to a domain relative path to the `style.css`, for example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" media="screen" />
```

If that is not possible, you need to keep track on the page base in some way, which I cannot tell because I do not know enough about your application. But anyway, like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $pageBase; ?>/style.css" media="screen" />
```

where $pageBase is a variable containing the url to the root of your application.

Comment: How to have the url to the root of my application ( localhost/do -> this is root of my application). Are there any function know $baseurl?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the `tem` directory is supposed to be for some sort of template, and so you don't want it to be directly exposed to the user; rather, you want to be able to include the files so that they're accessible via `index.php`, possibly with the option of later changing what files are included.

You could create another PHP file called `style.php` (in the root directory) which would include `tem/style.css`. You could do this for any other files that your templates used as well — the idea being that each PHP file in the root directory would correspond to a "role" in the template, not a particular template file, so that the template could later be changed without everything needing to be rewritten.

This might get a bit cumbersome if you had a lot of files required by your template, so it might be better to have a single script that could be instructed which file to load (through a `$_GET` variable). But in that case, you need to **be very careful** not to allow the user to specify arbitrary files. I'd suggest avoiding this approach until you're more proficient in PHP.

**EDIT**: On second thought, I'd suggest using a `<base>` tag in your template HTML file, as suggested in my comment on @gnud's answer.

Answer (score 0):

just always use absolute path to your css file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/tem/style.css" media="screen" />
```

that's all